# Prove LISP is not functional

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, procedural-programming

I'm in a discussion with a colleague in which he argues LISP is functional and I argue it is not.  While I concede that LISP programs *can* be written functionally, LISP is not "purely" functional (the way, I believe, Haskell is purported to be).

I am not a lisp expert (in fact, I'm a lisp beginner).  Could someone provide me with a lisp code-snippet that is unarguably not functional that I can show to him?  Thanks.

Comment: You need a formal definition of "functional" first.

Comment: ... and then you'd need to convince your buddy that this is the "right" definition. Or you could just stop fighting over buzzwords and characterize what you mean more accurately. You're trying to point out, for example, that Lisp permits mutable state? Then say *that*!

Comment: These questions are off-topic on Stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is for actual programming problems.

Answer (score 4):

The original LISP written by John MCcarthy in 1958 was purely functional. Side effects were not in the paper at all and since it didn't have `read`, `print` or `set` it was indeed a purely functional language. That changed when they made their interpreter though since they needed some way of loading a program, read results and `define` that worked as `setq` but you could define more than one function in the same form.

Like [ALGOL language family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generational_list_of_programming_languages#ALGOL_based) (consisting of almost all programming languages we know), LISP is now a [family of different languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generational_list_of_programming_languages#Lisp_based) as well. Some of LISP languages are functional but most of them are multi paradigm. Some, like the one used to make [Crash Bandicoot](http://all-things-andy-gavin.com/2011/03/12/making-crash-bandicoot-gool-part-9/) on the Playstation was very little dynamic and had bindings like stack/register and in reality more like a assembly/static language with LISP syntax. It was definitely not functional.

With LISP in the question I guess you meant `Common Lisp` and it is definitely not functional but a multi paradigm language and since it's not guaranteed to do [TCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail-call_optimization) you need to use `loop` where you in `Scheme` would use tail recursion. Many commonlispers would argue a function is functional as long as the mutation it does doesn't leak out, but in that perspective C++ can have functional functions too.

Scheme with it's shared namespace can do very hight percentage of functional code and it can become a function with side effects by giving it a different function to do the results with. I would say it can come close to Haskell if you want.

Side effects are a real fcuntional language killer, but without it your programs couldn't really do anything useful.